# Charset issue in HTML

Tags: html, css

I tested with my website in [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) and it says

> The following resources have a character set specified in a meta tag. Specifying a character set in a meta tag disables the lookahead downloader in IE8. To improve resource download parallelization, move the character set to the HTTP Content-Type response header.

Now it's like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

How can I solve this problem? I am using HTML 5 and CSS3.

Comment: Do as the message says: Return a *[`Content-Type` response header](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039)* with your page that specifies the content type. This is something you must do on the server, if it doesn't happen yet. This means changing something in the server configuration, .htaccess, PHP script... Do you have access to those?

Comment: Ya i have the credentials i will do that in server. Can you please give me the example for putting  those in my website like <meta http-......>

Comment: You might be able to get around this message by using HTML5's version `<meta charset="utf-8" />`, which (I believe) is ignored in those browsers

Comment: We can't tell you how to configure your webserver to specify the encoding in the HTTP header. You haven't told us what server you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is capable of running PHP, put the following code right at the top of your html file and rename it to whatever.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```